# cc.LabelTTF: spacing between characters

Tags: user-interface, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cclabelttf

Is there a way to change a space between characters? Some ttf font strings look very compressed.

The maximum closest thing I've managed to find is [cc.FontDefinition](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.0/symbols/cc.FontDefinition.html#constructor)
But it doesn't look like it contains anything specific I need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no method to change space between characters but you can change letters position via accessing it.

```
label.getLetter(index);
```

returns the character as a sprite. And then you can set its position.

Comment: unfortunately, it's available only for LabelBMFont (not for LabelTTF)

Comment: we use it in our games already. if you create your label just like: 
Label *label = Label::createWithTTF("text", "font", fontsize);
Then you can use getLetter(). There is no problem.

Comment: oh, I see, you're talking about c++. i didn't find getLetter wrapper in js binding.